# ImportError: No module named RPi

Tags: python, pi-3, packages

I am trying to run a package on my Raspberry Pi:

At the terminal, I typed in “sudo apt-get install picap” followed by enter.

I get it installed but cannot execute "picap-setup" – instead an error message follows:

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ picap-setup Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "", line 1, in  ImportError: No module named RPi

Python-dev and Rpi.GPIO are installed on the Pi.
I also updated the Pi with the latest version with sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.

Picap comes from :
https://www.bareconductive.com/make/setting-up-pi-cap-raspberry-pi/

I am thankful for any hints.

Comment: do you have pip installed???

Answer (score 31):

First of all, repeat following process

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip freeze | grep RPi
```

see what you get after this second command, If you get a valid module for RPi.GPIO or not.
And then following if not installed.

**For Python 2**

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-rpi.gpio
```

*or*

```
pip install RPi.GPIO
```

**For python3**

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-rpi.gpio
```

and then ( for python 2 or python 3):

```
sudo apt-get install picap
picap-setup
```

These all worked for me, Just you need to verify `pip freeze | grep RPi`. And one more thing sometimes some modules are not available for normal user only for root user. Make sure. I did all above using my `pi` user.

Comment: I would **not** use `pip` to install to system packages, either install from system package manager with `apt` or use `virtualenv` if you want to use pip.

Comment: Yeah thats correct, agreed

Comment: For Python3 use `sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-rpi.gpio`.

Comment: @crasic Could you explain why or point me in the direction of an explanation for simpletons? Thanks.

Comment: I get the following when trying to run picap-setup on my Raspberry Pi 4 with Python 3.7 in a virtualenv: 
`File "<stdin>", line 2
    print GPIO.RPI_INFO['TYPE']
             ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(GPIO.RPI_INFO['TYPE'])?`. 
It seems like this doesn't work with Python 3

Answer (score 6):

If Python RPi module is missing, one can install `pip` with all dependencies and then install the module using `pip` or go with the better approach and install the module alone:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio
```

for Python3 this one:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-rpi.gpio
```

Comment: Some appliances/JeOS doesn't support distro upgrade (like Volumio) and updating and installing a lot of dependencies can break the system, so this is another reason why to go low profile like that.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows

```
pip install python3-rpi.gpio
```

or

```
pip install RPi.GPIO
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with my Pi. Doing a simple pip install solved the issue.

```
pip install RPi.GPIO
```

Comment: This just repeats answers from 1 year ago.

Answer (score 0):

if using pycharm on windows then it will work like this

1. upgrade pip

   C:\Users\sandeep\PycharmProjects\newnum1\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
2. installing the module

   pip install RPi.GPIO
3. it worked for me should work for everyone

Comment: That answer has already been given - twice.

Comment: any of those didn't work for me so i provided my version that worked perfectly